# How do I customize the Control Panel login window?

Tags: control-panel

Is it possible to edit the EE Control Panel login window? A client would like to customize it with their company logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have follwed these [instructions](http://40horse.com/articles/article/custom_EE2_login_screen) for a couple of sites and found it to be pretty good to work with.

I like the idea that you don't have to alter EE (PHP) core files (you just change the stylesheet). Nevertheless after upgrading EE you have to reapply those changes to the stylesheet again. I guess you could also work with an import rule but the stylessheet is only about 120 lines and so easy enough to handle your custom changes.